# build conditional select with codeigniter form helpers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create two dropdown lists with the condition, that the second one should show the list based on the value, selected in the first one.
1st is city.
2nd is district within the city.
Both lists are populated from the database.

Here is an example

```
<td>City:</td>
<td>
    <?=form_dropdown('contact_city', $sel_city, set_value('contact_city'), "class='select2'"); ?>
</td>
<td>District:</td>
<td >
   <?=form_dropdown('contact_district', $sel_contact_district, set_value('contact_district'),"class='select2'"); ?>
</td>
```

$sel_contact_district should be reloaded and list selection updated after city value is changed.

Which approach should I use?

Comment: If you're using ajax it's easy. You will make a function that will receive a parameter: `$city_id` (you choose the name). From this ID you search the database for all districts in this city. Return them with a key/value pairs and populate the select.

Comment: From your code I noticed you're probably using select2. It has a function for populating via ajax.

Comment: Which event should call the function you suggest?

Comment: You should populate the district dropdown on the "change" event of the city dropdown.

Comment: Something like that: https://pastebin.com/tbXt7FXu

Comment: [simple example](http://www.freewebmentor.com/2015/05/responsive-countrystatecity-dropdown-using-php.html)
Search web engines first.

Answer (score 0):

Select2 supports methods that allow programmatic control of the component.

// var $example = $(".js-example-programmatic").select2();

```
$('body').on('click', '.select2', function(e) {   
    //var select_name = $(this).attr("your_select2_name");
    $(this).val("your_option").trigger("change"); 
});
```

You can also add options like this:

```
$('.select2').select2('data', {id: 100, a_key: 'Lorem Ipsum'});
```

3rd Edit:
As you mention in your question that you need to select the option on the select dropdown to depend on the first dropdown selected option. 
Here is the Two select box which changes the option depending on the first select box.

```
$("#select1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
 /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
 $(this).data('options', $('#select2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#select2').html(options);
});
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <option value="1">Fruit</option>
  <option value="2">Animal</option>
  <option value="3">Bird</option>
  <option value="4">Car</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
  <option value="1">Banana</option>
  <option value="1">Apple</option>
  <option value="1">Orange</option>
  <option value="2">Wolf</option>
  <option value="2">Fox</option>
  <option value="2">Bear</option>
  <option value="3">Eagle</option>
  <option value="3">Hawk</option>
  <option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, Phiter, Ankit. I wil try and share the results.

Comment: I got your idea. But I have several "select2" elements on my form. $(".select2").on("click", function () works, but it runs for each "select2" element. I tried $("#my_element").on("click", function () .... it doesn't work. How can I either differentiate which select was changed or handle event only for the particular select? Thanks

Comment: Ok, as you said that you have multiple `select2` is that all have same `name` attribute or different if they have different `name` then you can find them by name.

Comment: I have edited my answer can you please update me regarding current status of your question. @ЮрийОнищенко

Comment: I have Edited Answer @ЮрийОнищенко

Comment: It's really strange, but when I use element id like $("#select1").change(function() {... it doesn't work (I mean #select1). So, I tried another approach:     $('.select2').select2()
  .on('change', function(e){
   if (e.currentTarget.name=='contact_city') {
    
   }
  });  ..... and IT WORKS. So, it's possible to handle events extending the class, but not the element...

Comment: finally next code works:$('<option value='+ 1 +'>'+ 'Mountain' +'</option>').appendTo('select[name=contact_district]');
    $('select[name=contact_district]').select2('val',1);   So everything was around syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using ajax you could populate the second dropdown based on the value of the first. Would look something like that:

```
$("#cityDropdown").on('change', function(){
    $.post('api/listdistrictsfromcity',
           { city_id : $(this).val() },
           function(response){
               var $district_dropdown = $("#districtsDropdown").empty();   
               $.each(response, function(i, item){
                    $district_dropdown.append("<option value='" + item.value + "'>"+ item.text +"</option>");
               });
           });
});
```